# How can i get this Object from my api call am using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Am trying to access my api that return an object with an array of data but i cant access am getting an error saying Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ am using retrofit into my android application

*Here is what the api returns when i call it*

```
{
"students": [
    {
        "_id": "5e74775518b0f00c0123925b",
        "registrationno": "IWR/D/2016/0024",
        "firstname": "Mariam",
        "lastname": "Wamigomba",
        "amount": 10000,
        "reason": "lost key ",
        "__v": 0
    }]}
```

**here is my interface**

```
public interface OcappJsonApiSNAL {
    @GET("getStudents")
    Call<List<StudentClearanceSNAL>> getStudents(@Header ("Authorization") String token);
}
```

**On my java class**

```
OcappJsonApiSNAL ocappJsonApi = retrofit.create (OcappJsonApiSNAL.class);
Call<List<StudentClearanceSNAL>> listCall = ocappJsonApi.getStudents ("Bearer token");
listCall.enqueue (new Callback<List<StudentClearanceSNAL>> () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<StudentClearanceSNAL>> call, Response<List<StudentClearanceSNAL>> response) {
        if(!response.isSuccessful ()) {
            Toast.makeText (getActivity (),"From OCApp " + response.code (),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            return;
        }
        List<StudentClearanceSNAL> studentClearancess = response.body ();
           for (  final StudentClearanceSNAL studentClearance: studentClearancess)
                        {
```

**Error Am Getting**

`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Comment: this error usually occurs if your POJO class is wrong. So can you share your POJO class too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Call<List<StudentClearanceSNAL>> listCall = ocappJsonApi.getStudents ("Bearer token");
```

Instead of map list externally  you just create new model with list

**Create new model :**

```
 Class StudentClearanceSNALList{
 @SerializedName("students") // it’s must match with your Jason object name
 List<StudentClearanceSNAL> studentClearanceSNAL = new Arraylist<>();
//getter and setter
}
```

Then update your interface and class like the following code:

**Interface:**

```
public interface OcappJsonApiSNAL {
    @GET("getStudents")
    Call<StudentClearanceSNALList> getStudents(@Header ("Authorization") String token);
}
```

**Class :**

```
OcappJsonApiSNAL ocappJsonApi = retrofit.create (OcappJsonApiSNAL.class);
Call<StudentClearanceSNALList> listCall = ocappJsonApi.getStudents ("Bearer token");
listCall.enqueue (new Callback<StudentClearanceSNALList> () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<StudentClearanceSNALList> call, Response<StudentClearanceSNALList> response) {
        if(!response.isSuccessful ()) {
            Toast.makeText (getActivity (),"From OCApp " + response.code (),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            return;
        }
 StudentClearanceSNALList studentClearancess = response.body ();
```

Why I suggest this means it’s expect list but you pass object so it’s not accept so please use the above code.

I hope it’s helps you thanks

Comment: it htrows this error saying  Required type:
Call
<StudentCleranceSNALList>
Provided:
Call
<List<StudentClearanceSNAL> brother what am i missing

Comment: Can you share the full code please  and please don’t forget to add @SerializedName annotation in your model.

Comment: please add full error track also it’s help me to understand better

Comment: Can you confirm update StudentClearanceSNALLList in interface and class

Comment: the code your provided am to add it on the interface too right

Comment: Yes you need to replace with old List<yourobject>  To newly created model yourobjectList

Comment: okay let e  that brother will inform you if it will work brother

Comment: Ok keep on post your status

Comment: sorry brother am confused am kinda new to retrofit where exactly do i put the model you created up there or can you show me how the interface will now look like thanks

Comment: have also updated my qns by adding a new code that am looping through the response

Comment: I request you to update question status to complete it’s helps to other people.. it’s my small request please update question status if my answer is correct update that also my brother

Comment: brother one more problem on looping is the problem

Comment: for (  final StudentClearanceSNALIst studentClearance: studentClearancess)
                            {

Comment: it says foreach is not applicable to type on my class

Comment: @KyleMutta  for(StudentClearancessSNAL student : studentClearancess.getStudentClearancess()){} use this